# Trouble importing images with Pillow / TCL struggles

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-imaging-library

I'm getting some errors trying to use Pillow to import pictures that make me feel like I'm running in circles. My code follows the 'Toolbar' example [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/menustoolbars/).

I got this error to start with:

```
objc[571]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[571]: Class TKMenu is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[571]: Class TKContentView is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[571]: Class TKWindow is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

After looking at previous StackOverflow posts, I decided to uninstall version 8.6 to fix the version conflict. However, after I did that, I received this error since version 8.6 can no longer be found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()  
  File "untitled.py", line 61, in main
    app = Example(root)
  File "untitled.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "untitled.py", line 41, in initUI
    eimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)  
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 180, in paste
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/PIL/_imagingtk.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/PIL/_imagingtk.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Hanners 1/.python-eggs/Pillow-3.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/PIL/_imagingtk.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/Tcl
  Referenced from: /Users/Hanners 1/.python-eggs/Pillow-3.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/PIL/_imagingtk.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!